# NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse when using AST

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, abstract-syntax-tree

When trying to use an AST in a java project in eclipse, I get this error message is runtime:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdaptable

I've tried adding to the build path the core.runtime jar, but that didn't help.

The code fails right on the beginning:

```
AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS4);
```

I also tried adding all the jars in my computer but to no avail. any ideas?

stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdaptable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at testRun.main(testRun.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Did you make an executable jar?

Comment: It would help if you posted your stack trace

Comment: No Jar, running by pressing 'play' on eclipse.

Comment: Have you done anything to adjust the Target Platform?  What's the text of the button where you pressed 'play'?  Are you developing a plug-in or a Java Application?  Give more specifics.

Answer (score 4):

Besides adding `org.eclipse.jdt.core_[version_number].jar` to your Build Path, you also need to add **`org.eclipse.equinox.common_[version_number].jar`**.

Comment: @Templar because class `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable` is defined in package `org.eclipse.equinox.common`

Comment: @Sean I have both of these jars (org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.6.0.v20100503 and org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.0.v_B61), but am still getting the same exception. Does the version number need to be the same for both jars? I also have org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.1.0.jar which has IAdaptable class as well. Even when I remove this jar, it still gives the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShreyansPagariya I think you should use the compatable version(like keeping all these jars latest. search from mvnrepo); make sure these jars are added to your classpath